# How to start Rethinkdb as windows service

Tags: rethinkdb

I'm not able to create `Rethinkdb` as windows service.
Done research on websites but did not found anything useful.

I have one option to create scheduler on windows startup.

Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's pywin32 to implement the Windows Service. You can use my MTWService [1] as boilerplate. You'll need to change it to run RethinkDB instead of a Tornado based web server. To do that hack mtwservice.py [2]. Pay special attention to the comment at the top of the source, and change the SvcDoRun method to launch RethinkDB as a child process instead of python.exe. Good luck!

[1] https://github.com/osullivj/MTWService
[2] https://github.com/osullivj/MTWService/blob/master/mtwservice.py